# GEV of Normal Distribution and relationship of the parameters

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, extreme-value

My question goes on Extreme Value Theory for the Normal distribution ([www.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/RM/chap7.pdf](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/RM/chap7.pdf)):

1. Which type of GEV (Generalized Extreme Value) distribution does the Normal distribution belong to (Weibull/Gumbel/Frechet)?
2. If we have the Normal parameters given ($\mu, \sigma$), can we infer the parameter values of its GEV?

Comment: 1. See the second paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).

Comment: @emcor Your link to chap7.pdf is broken good sir! Moreover, could someone summarize the answers to yes / no + explanation? Especially since Wikipedia is updated from time to time. On a related note the here-link should be https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gumbel_distribution&oldid=610802871