# Extreme value distribution for univariate normal: Derive parameters of the Gumbel

Tags: normal-distribution, extreme-value, gumbel-distribution

I have a question regarding the extreme value distribution corresponding to i.i.d. samples $X_i$ from a normal distribution, say $X_i\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

According to the theorem of Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko, the maximum follows a Gumbel distribution: $max(X_i)\sim Gumbel(\alpha, k)$ with location $\alpha$ and scale $k$. I would like to express these parameters in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, i.e. as a function of the parameters of the underlying normal distribution.

I didn't find any clear indication in the literature how this can be done, and yet it should be simple. By playing around with simulations, where I simulated the $X_i$ for a certain range of $\sigma$ and $\mu$ and then estimate $\alpha$ and $k$ with the MLE, I found the following linear relationships:

$\alpha\approx 2.92\sigma+\mu$

$k\approx 0.306\sigma$

These relationships were estimated with the OLS and achieved a high $R^2$. They make intuitively sense to me, but I was wondering if and how they can be derived analytically.

My question is similar to (2) of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104310/gev-of-normal-distribution-and-relationship-of-the-parameters) question from 2014, which was never answered though. Also, it bears some similarity to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105745). However, in that
In that article the question is to show convergence. My question is related to a different aspect, namely deriving the parameters of the distribution once we assume that convergence holds

Comment: I don't know anything about extreme value theory, but as a starting point, you may want to show that $\left[\Phi\left(\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^n$ is the CDF of $\max_i(X_i)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.